# Angular Formarray static data

Tags: angular, typescript

I have got shop values(array of string) from another component and saved it to localstorage. Now I want to add this values into formarray named shopIds.There will not be any input form field in HTML file. But after form sumbit shopIds are getting null. How can I do this. I am adding codes here:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.formInit();
    const shopIdsStr = localStorage.getItem('cdk-shop-list');
    if (shopIdsStr) {
      this.shop = JSON.parse(shopIdsStr);
      console.log(this.shop);
    }
  }

formInit = () => {
    this.couponForm = new FormGroup({
      shopIDs: this.formBuilder.array([this.shop]),
    });
  };
```

[image: this is the log of this.shop]

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the form before getting values from the local storage. That's why the value is null.

**Update:** Since you are only storing static data which will not have any input control, you should not use `FromArray`. Instead, use a FromControl and set its value to the array of strings. It will be passed to the backend in the form of an array (just like your scenario).

```
formInit = () => {
    this.couponForm = new FormGroup({
      shopIDs: new FormControl(this.shop), //Set default value to shop array
    });
  };
```

> Form Array aggregates the values and validity state of its child controls. It holds an array of Abstract controls.

That's why you were getting errors like Cannot read
property '_rawValidators' of undefined

---

Call the `this.forminit()` method after reading values from local storage.

```
this.shop=[]; // Or initialize it with null according to your Backend contract.
ngOnInit(): void {
   
    const shopIdsStr = localStorage.getItem('cdk-shop-list');
    if (shopIdsStr) {
      this.shop = JSON.parse(shopIdsStr);
      console.log(this.shop);
    }
     this.formInit(); //Call Here
  }
```

Comment: I have initialized like this : shop: string[] = [];

Now after calling formInit down there there's some error in console like this:

1. this.validator is not a function
2. Cannot read property '_rawValidators' of undefined
3.  Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Comment: Updated my answer with the correct approach for your scenario